# Is it possible to upload an Azure BLOB + metadata in a single call?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

[All the examples I see for setting metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata) for an Azure BLOB show 2 distinct calls. Is there a call that uploads both the BLOB and the metadata? In C# for a Blazor app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so. You can use [`UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) and specify metadata in [`BlobUploadOptions.Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions.metadata?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-metadata)

Comment: Thank you. I looked but clearly I didn't dive deep enough.